# Flash:AS3: Button click to trigger the right arrow key?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a button basically trigger right arrow key when it is clicked.   If someone could help me out with a code to do this I would greatly appreciate it!  Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is a bad idea.

If you want the mouse button to perform the same operation as the key, you should refactor the code to a shared method:

```
function doSomething(){
    // ...
}

function mouseClick(){
    doSomething();
}

function keyPress(){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?
I will only be using this button one time.  It is just an alternitive for the arrow key.

Comment: @Kudla69 Its a horrible concept. Your action essentially depends on mouse input, then your mouse input depends on your key input. Your actions should be independent from the input. If they require information about the input, you should pass the data in such a way that it is independent.

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up your keystroke management similar to me then it should be easy..

I basically just have a class with an array which has a given index set to true/false based on the `keyCode` of the pressed/released key..

A breakdown of this:

When I press "a" which has an ASCII or keyCode value of 65, then `array[65]` is set to `true`. When I release the "a" key, `array[65]` is set to `false`.

Then I just have a function that returns a boolean that represents a key being held down. Here's a quick example of this class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Keystrokes
    {
        public static var keys:Array = [];

        public static function init(stg:Stage):void
        {
            stg.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyDown);
            stg.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, _keyUp);
        }

        private static function _keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }

        private static function _keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            delete keys[e.keyCode];
        }

        public static function keyIsDown(...ascii):Boolean
        {
            var i:uint;
            for each(i in ascii)
            {
                if(keys[i]) return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now with all that said you could basically do:

`Keystrokes.keys[keycode_for_right_arrow] = true;`

When you click the mouse, and `false` when you release it.